# 80's story about siblings going to another realm, one falls ill in the real world and must be saved through the other one.

Tags: story-identification

It was about a boy who went into some other realm with his brother (I think), his brother got ill or was wounded there and was now dying in the real world. The brother had to go back to the other realm to save him. I seem to remember that he went back with a girl and they rode on lily pads at some point. There were weird black flying things that were trying to get them.

Not much to go on I know but I am trying to remember it so that I can get it for my daughter.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144906/which-1970s-uk-fantasy-kids-tv-show-has-an-older-brother-die

Answer (score 3):

How about Astrid Lindgren's The [Brothers Lionheart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brothers_Lionheart) from the 70's? In the story, there are two brothers who, after dying, reincarante in a world called Nangijala. Over there, an evil overlord rules the land with a dragon. The story is quite dark for a children's tale; in the end

> the brothers commit a suicide in order to reincarnate into yet another a world.

Answer (score 2):

Parts of that resonate with the Raymond Feist book, [Faerie Tale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faerie_Tale). It's basically a visitation of the faeries on their 6 month sojourn, and the troubles they cause a family due to the influence of the dark elements among the Daonie Sidhe element. One of the boys is kidnapped into the faerie realm and replaced with a changeling, and his brother has to go into the realm to rescue him.

They had a sister that was assaulted and plays other parts in the novel, but she did not go into the realm with them.

Answer (score 1):

A long shot, but [A Wrinkle in Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_wrinkle_in_time) has a brother and sister teleporting to other worlds looking for their missing father.  They are opposed by something called "The Black Thing".  Other vague fit: at one point the brother and sister are separated, the sister gets quite ill and then has to go and rescue the brother.